# Handling out of range list index in Python 2.7

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, error-handling

I have a list of lists in Python 2.7, just like the one shown below

```
rr =[[10 for row in range(5)] for col in range(5)]
```

Now, in my algorithm, where I need to find the neighbours of a given list element, I used the following way of checking for neighbours

```
b = [rr[rn][cn+1],rr[rn-1][cn+1],rr[rn-1][cn],rr[rn-1][cn-1],rr[rn][cn-1],rr[rn+1][cn-1],rr[rn+1][cn],rr[rn+1][cn+1]]
```

I want to assign `0` to the neighbouring elements that are outside the boundary of the given matrix (or list)

where `rn` is the row index, and `cn` is the column index of the list cell that I wanted to inspect. Given above, what iff my code checks any corner cell ? like say the first row and first column cell element with index `[0,0]`, some of the neighbours index will be negative. My code has a special property that it prevents me to add additional rows or columns to the list indicated above.

How to deal with this ? any help....

Comment: agreed, it has to be rr[a][b] instead of rr[a,b]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to solve both the bound problem and the `rr[i,j]` syntax, you can overload the `getitem` method in a class:

```
class boundedlist(list):
    def __getitem__(self,indices):
        try: 
            l=list(self)
            for i in indices : l=l[i]
            return l
        except IndexError:
            return 0
```

Then all works like you want :

```
In [76]: brr=boundedlist(rr)

In [77]: brr[4,3]
Out[77]: 10

In [78]: brr[4,6]
Out[78]: 0

In [79]: brr[-1,6]
Out[79]: 0

In [80]: brr[10,4]
Out[80]: 0
```

You keep the row acces like that:

```
In [81]: brr[[4]]
Out[81]: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

and you can generalize to more dimensions. You will have to adapt `__setitem__` if you want to modify the data.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to access `cell(1,1)` in `rr` list you have to use `rr[1][1]`

```
for i in range(len(rr)):
    for j in range(len(rr[i])):
        if (i, j) in [(rn, cn+1), (rn-1,cn+1 ), (rn-1, cn ), (rn-1, cn-1 ), (rn, cn-1 ), (rn+1, cn-1 ), (rn+1, cn ), (rn+1, cn+1)]:
            #Do some things
        else:
            #Do other things
```

Comment: This works well to skip out of range lists, but just curious....is there any way that we can assign values to those out range indexed elements ?